# Can I use substitution in multivariable calculus?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to solve this limit, and as you can see, if I make $u=x^2+y^2$ then the problem is almost solved; but my question is if it is valid to use such thing because you're going from two variables to one and that doesn't make really much sense to me.

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2\sin\left( x^2+y^2 \right) +x^4}{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: Yes, you can, since $x^2+y^2\to 0$ iff $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. Just be careful with how you deal with that $x^4$, though.

Comment: What Answer did you get? I think you can make that substitution. This could also be done in Polar Coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a substitution in this case because $u\to 0$ if and only if $x^2+y^2\to 0$ if and only if $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. You can also make a polar coordinate transformation (which is fairly standard) using: $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. Then $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and the limit becomes
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{2\sin(r^2)+r^4\cos^4(\theta)}{r^2}=\lim_{r\to 0}\left(\frac{2\sin(r^2)}{r^2}+r^2\cos^4(\theta)\right)$$
Can you show that $$\lim_{r\to 0}\left(\frac{2\sin(r^2)}{r^2}\right)$$ and $$\lim_{r\to 0}\left(r^2\cos^4(\theta)\right)$$
exists, and can you find their values?

Comment: You have to be careful with this kind of stuff.  $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$ transforms to $\lim \frac{2r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{r^2}=\lim \sin(2\theta)$ which looks like it should be $0$, but in fact this limit does not exist.

Comment: Fabulous! ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Callus indeed, the limit must hold for all values of $\theta$.